# How to have a single component route default to a component Angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular application, In there I have a component that needs show on two routes before each subsequent components: i.e.

Service > List (same Component) > Request

Floor > List (same Component) > Floor request

When the user selects the service route, I want the list component to show as default and the same with the floor route.

Would I do something like this:

```
{
    path: 'service',
    component: serviceComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'list', component: listComponent },
    ]
  },
```

But how would it default to the list if service was selected?

Comment: you want to call same component from 2 different route?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe what you want is simply to replace `path: 'list'` by `path: ''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First method:

You can achieve it by using parameter

```
{path: 'service', component: ServiceComponent},
{path: 'floor', component: FloorComponent},
{path: 'list/:type', component: ListComponent}
```

**ListComponent**

To be able to get the parameter you need to follow few steps.

Add this import

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

Inject it to `constructor()`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And add to `constructor()` or into `ngOnInit()` subscribe on `params`

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(params.type);
      // Here you can make request based on params.type
    });
```

The URL will look like this `http://localhost:4200/list/service` or `http://localhost:4200/list/floor`

### Second method:

Or you can set `data` property to `route` in Angular Router.

```
{path: 'service',
    component: ServiceComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'list', component: ListComponent, data: {requestType: 'service'}}
]},
{path: 'floor',
    component: FloorComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'list', component: ListComponent, data: {requestType: 'floor'}}
]},
```

**ListComponent**

> The rest is very similar to first method

Add this import

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

Inject it to `constructor()`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

The only difference will be here because you need to subscribe to `data`

```
this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data.requestType);
  //Here you can make request based on data.requestType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{path: 'service',
    component: serviceComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'list', component: listComponent}
]},
{path: 'floor',
    component: floorComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'list', component: listComponent}
]},
```

What I did was just setting the default route to those components. And it will redirect you to list.